# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on response

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, arraylist

I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error on SoapUI. I used loggers to check if `record` holds the right `StartTime` and `EndTime` but for some reason I get that error when I try to add the `record` object which contains `userId` and `TimePeriod` into the response. Also, `result` is the variable which has the info returned from the `DataAccess` layer. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
GetUserResponse response = new GetUserResponse();
UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
record.UserId = userId;
record.timePeriodList = new List<TimePeriod>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i += 2)
{
    TimePeriod timeData = new TimePeriod();
    timeData.StartTime = result[i].Time;
    timeData.EndTime = result[i + 1].Time;
    record.timePeriodList.Add(timeData);
}
response.UserRecordList.Add(record); // line I get that error
```

Here is the code to my response:

```
public class GetUserResponse
{
    private List<UserRecord> userRecordList;

    public List<UserRecord> UserRecordList
    {
        get { return userRecordList; }
        set { userRecordList = value; }
    }
}

public class UserRecord
{
    private string userId;
    private List<TimePeriod> timePeriodList;

    public string UserId
    {
        get { return userId; }
        set { userId = value; }
    }

    public List<RbeActivationPeriod> TimePeriodList
    {
        get { return timePeriodList; }
        set { timePeriodList = value; }
    }
}

public class TimePeriod
{
    private DateTime startTime;
    private DateTime endTime;

    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return startTime; }
        set { startTime = value; }
    }

    public DateTime EndTime
    {
        get { return endTime; }
        set { endTime = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `response` declared? Is `userRecordList` instantiated?

Comment: I can't see it in your code but I assume that you have instantiated your variable response?

Comment: @erik I edited the post for you. Sorry forgot the declaration on the post.

Comment: @DarrenDavies yes response is declared. Does userRecordList need to be initiated? I have edited the post to reflect changes. Thanks

Comment: Problem line is `timeData.EndTime = result[i + 1].Time;`

Comment: Why do you suspect that? `record` holds the right info from what got returned from the logger @Satpal

Comment: I'm thinking you need to declare a new instance of userRecordList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a new instance of the list `UserRecordList` as it will be `null` when you attempt to insert an element.

```
GetUserResponse response = new GetUserResponse();
response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();
```

Alternatively you can add this at the class level or in the constructor.

```
public class GetUserResponse
{
    private List<UserRecord> userRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();

    public List<UserRecord> UserRecordList
    {
        get { return userRecordList; }
        set { userRecordList = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.` on that response.add line now

Comment: @user4756836 - most likely this line `timeData.EndTime = result[i + 1].Time;` however this is a different question so you should accept this as the answer (It appears to have solved your problem) and repost a new question with the index out of range exception.